# Keep campaigns tracking with multiple GA accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 google analytics accounts for 2 subdomains (www-exemple.com and s.exemple.com)
Users have to go through www-exemple to get to s.exemple

My question is : 
How can i keep track of the campaigns in my 2 GA accounts. 
If a user came to 'www-exemple' with a 'BLABLABLA' campaign, how can i know if he continued his navigation to 's.exemple' and get the same 'BLABLABLA' campaign on my second GA account

The purpose is to know if a campaign managed to make a user go to 'www-exemple' and then to 's.exemple'

Thx !

Comment: You can achieve what you want with funnels: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en

Comment: Is there a reason you are using 2 separate accounts? If you used the same account across both subdomains then GA will automatically keep track of campaign sources as the user moves between sections of your site.